# What is difference of CSSearchableIndex and NSUserActivity in Search API? How often call?

Tags: ios, ios-searchapi

I see below code in iOS9Sampler to use `Search API` in iOS 9. It use both `NSUserActivity` and `CSSearchableIndex`. So I want to ask question:

1. When should use `NSUserActivity`, when should use `CSSearchableIndex`? I see it make same result when search in Spotlight.
2. Below code call every `viewDidLoad` of view controller. Is it correct? Or should it call only one time? How can I check to call one time?

*NSUserActivity*

```
    let activityType = String(format: "%@.%@", uniqueIdentifier, domainIdentifier)
    activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: activityType)
    activity.title = "iOS-9-Sampler_NSUserActivity"
    activity.keywords = Set<String>(arrayLiteral: "dog", "cat", "pig", "sheep")
    activity.eligibleForSearch = true
    activity.becomeCurrent()
```

*Core Spotlight*

```
    let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeImage as String)
    attributeSet.title = "iOS-9-Sampler_CoreSpotlight"
    attributeSet.contentDescription = "iOS-9-Sampler is a code example collection for new features of iOS 9."
    attributeSet.keywords = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "fish"]
    let image = UIImage(named: "m7")!
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    attributeSet.thumbnailData = data

    let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(
        uniqueIdentifier: uniqueIdentifier,
        domainIdentifier: domainIdentifier,
        attributeSet: attributeSet)

    CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([searchableItem]) { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("failed with error:\(error)\n")
        }
        else {
            print("Indexed!\n")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of content you're indexing and how the user interacts with it will determine if it's appropriate to use `NSUserActivity` or `CSSearchableItem`.

This is explained in the [App Search Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308), and examples are provided for a couple different scenarios, so be sure to review this thoroughly. Some notes:

- Use `NSUserActivity` to index items as users perform activities in
  your app, such as visiting a navigation point or creating and viewing
  content.
- Use Core Spotlight to add app-specific content to the on-device
  index, such as persistent user data - documents, photos, and other
  types of content.
- `CSSearchableItem` does not require the user visit the content,
  unlike `NSUserActivity`.
- `CSSearchableItem` is not publicly indexable, while `NSUserActivity`
  is.